# Can't delete file after writing to it

Tags: java, file, io

I have a problem with deleting the file after I wrote to it. Here is the code of writing to it:

```
String xml = "blablaxml";
Path file = Paths.get("file.xml");
Files.write(file, xml.getBytes());
```

Here I want to delete it:

```
Files.deleteIfExists(file);
```

The error:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: file.xml: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I debugged the code and just before trying to delete the file I used Microsoft Process Explorer and the file is not used by any process, so I don't understand the error.

Comment: After creating the file did you open it with any software?

Comment: If you really need to use java.nio, then write using sync mode.

`Files.write(file, xml.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.SYNC);`

Comment: I didn't open it with any software and if I use the StandardOpenOption.SYNC I get NoSuchFileException

Comment: Are you saying that you write the file and delete it without doing anything with it? Then why do you write it in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

The error message is clear, you can't delete the file because it is used by another process or thread. Make sure you close the file stream after you finished writing into the file before you delete. See [How to create a file and write to a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)

Comment: He's using java.nio.

Comment: He can see the link in my answer to see how to write to a file otherwise and close.

Comment: Downvoting because he already does what's described in the best answer of the post you linked, under the title 'Java7+ users - creating a binary file'

Comment: @ThomasKläger what's wrong in me referencing an answer that does what I already explained? Besides the link is not entirely the answer to the question asked!